# Как посчитать итоговые углы при повороте системы координат в 3D?

Tags: матрицы, геометрия, вектор

Есть базовая система координат в углах `0;0;0`
Есть повёрнутая относительно неё система в углах `35;45;90`
Хочу повернуть систему2 на +45 градусов, вокруг её Y (т.е. `0;45;0`).

Как мне посчитать итоговые углы, относительно базовой системы?
Результат ожидается `102.6;65.5;167.4` (причем проверка на глаз, показала, что и `-77;116;-12` тоже подходят, и вероятно многие другие).

Comment: Что-то у вас какой-то странный ожидаемый результат. Было 35 по H (heading), при повороте на угол <45 (какая бы ни была ориентация, итоговый поворот по каждой из осей будет меньше чем общий) стало 102.6 ? Перепроверяйте, или уточняйте условие.

Comment: Тут интересное дело: ориентируюсь в ожидаемом результате по пакету моделирования роботов RobCAD. Такие интересные цифры он выдаёт. Причём, созданная новая система координат,  с ориентацией 0;0;0 будучи последовательно повёрнута вокруг Z, Y, X на углы указанные мной в качестве ожидаемых - попадает туда же, где и должна быть.

Comment: А вам вообще нужны эти углы? Может все делать в кватернионах/матрицах?

Comment: А вектор для проверки вы точно поворачиваете, направленный из начала координат? Если есть скриншоты - лучше приложите.

Comment: Углы нужны. Координаты всех интересующих меня точек (речь идёт о шестиосевом роботе) я рассчитал сам, а вот углы систем координат на каждом звене - не получается)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь и отклик в любом случае! Но, пусть результирующие значения не смущают Вас, возможно у RobCAD свой взгляд на вещи (а это, отчасти так). Вопрос скорее в другом: какова методика вычисления этих углов? Например, я пытался вычислить результирующие углы через перемножение "матрицы поворота через углы Эйлера", где в качестве углов брал углы системы2 (35, 45, 90) на матрицу с до-поворотом (0,45,0) - получалось не то при визуальной проверке.

Comment: да, работаю из начала координат

Comment: Хотите прикол? Тот же итоговый результат дают и углы -77, 116, -12 (подобрал на глаз). И множество других тоже ..

Comment: проверил, да, Ваш вариант практически в точку) Но, какова методика расчёта, кроме как на глаз? )